# nginx-ingress error page not hide nginx version

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a problem configuring nginx-ingress, so I'm asking you a question.
There is a problem getting the server version with HTTP Header and nginx in the annotation.ingress. Resolved by adding kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:
But the Nginx version keeps appearing on the error page, what should I do?

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes,io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: more_clear_headers "Server";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 2048m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-tokens: 'false'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
```

Comment: Could you share the exact error you are getting? You want that page to appear but without the Nginx version?

Comment: Hi Shine, welcome to SO. Be aware that `configuration-snippet:` applies only to the `location {}` implemented by the Ingress resource; you likely want [`server-tokens: "false"` in the ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-tokens) which applies to the whole nginx server

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes The Nginx version appears at the bottom of the default 404 error page. I want to modify the version so that it doesn't come out.

Comment: @mdaniel thanks, i find configmap settings data. `server-tokens: "off"` and data. `proxy-hide-headers: "Server"`